# Como inserir dados Json no mysql usando php

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tenho um documento com dados do formato json que quero inserir na BD phpmyadmin, estou a conseguir inserir os primeiros dados na tabela que estão dentro de "results", mas não estou a conseguir entrar no "catechisms_students_attributes" , deixo abaixo e guardar "education_sponsor_description".

Documento Json:

```
 {
    results: [
    {
    catechist_description: "Albertina Dinis",
    class_year: "2017/2018",
    finalized: true,
    id: 33,
    is_for_adults: false,
    name: "catequese 2o",
    start_time: "23:00",
    week_day: "7",
    year: 2,
    catechisms_students_attributes: [
    {
    catechism_id: 33,
    created_at: "2017-10-19T15:47:49",
    deleted: false,
    education_sponsor_description: "José Paulo Almeida Bernardes",
    education_sponsor_id: 173486,
    entity_description: "Manuel Rocha",
    entity_id: 173502,
    id: 154,
    inscription_date: "2017-10-19",
    observations: null,
    transferred: false,
    updated_at: "2017-10-19T15:47:49"
    },
    {
    catechism_id: 33,
    created_at: "2017-11-04T11:04:45",
    deleted: false,
    education_sponsor_description: "Manuel Rocha",
    education_sponsor_id: 173502,
    entity_description: "teste",
    entity_id: 185503,
    id: 156,
    inscription_date: "2017-11-04",
    observations: null,
    transferred: false,
    updated_at: "2017-11-04T11:04:45"
    }
    ],
    }
```

O código que estou a usar:

```
    curl_close($ch3);
    $decode_catechisms = json_decode($response3, true);


    foreach ($decode_catechisms["results"] as $catechisms_object) {
        $id_catechisms = $catechisms_object['id'];
        $catechist_description = $catechisms_object['catechist_description'];
        $class_year = $catechisms_object['class_year'];
        $catechist_name = $catechisms_object['name'];
        $start_time = $catechisms_object['start_time'];
        $week_day = $catechisms_object['week_day'];
        $catechism_year = $catechisms_object['year'];
        $education_sponsor_description = $catechisms_object['catechisms_students_attributes']['education_sponsor_description'];


//insert into mysql table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO catechisms (id_catequese, catechist_description, class_year, name, start_time, week_day, year, education_sponsor_description)
    VALUES('$id_catechisms','$catechism_year', '$class_year', '$catechist_name','$start_time', '$week_day', '$catechism_year', '$education_sponsor_description')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    id_catequese='$id_catechisms', catechist_description='$catechist_description', class_year='$class_year', name='$catechist_name',"
                . " start_time='$start_time', week_day='$week_day', year='$catechism_year', education_sponsor_description='$education_sponsor_description'";
```

O erro que me está a dar é **"Notice: Undefined index: education_sponsor_description"**
Será que me podiam ajudar?

Comment: Da um var_dump no `$catechisms_object['catechisms_students_attributes']`

Comment: Boa noite, já fiz e imprime os dados corretamente tal como estão dentro de 'cathechisms_students_attributes' daí não perceber o porquê de não inserir e dar erro.

´array(2) { [0]=> array(12) { ["catechism_id"]=> int(33) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2017-10-19T15:47:49" ["deleted"]=> bool(false) ["education_sponsor_description"]=> string(29) "José Paulo Almeida Bernardes" ["education_sponsor_id"]=> int(173486) ["entity_description"]=> string(12) "Manuel Rocha" ["entity_id"]=> int(173502) ["id"]=> int(154) ["inscription_date"]=> string(10) "2017-10-19" ["observations"]=> ...`

Comment: Mas caso faça var_dump de $catechisms_object['catechisms_students_attributes']['education_sponsor_description'], imprime NULL

Comment: O erro é porque os dados estão duplicados, para acessar esse valor você tem que colocar um indice na frente: `$education_sponsor_description = $catechisms_object['catechisms_students_attributes'][0]['education_sponsor_description'];`